# Live update the text content that lies within a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a basic calculator using css, html and js. I have a function as follows:

```
        document.getElementById('user_radius').onkeyup = function () 

        {
            document.getElementById('live_update').innerHTML = this.value;
        }
```

Basically, whatever is typed into the user text box is supposed to live update the text that lies within the span tag with the id of "live_update". I have a text box with an id of user_radius. I save changes and can't get the text to live update. Am I missing a basic principle here?

Comment: what do you mean by "save changes" ? if you're reloading the page then all changes will be lost unless you use something like localstorage [ Local storage W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to do it

1.mix javascript and DOM. This makes it a little difficult to debug your stuff in the future.

```
<input id='user_radius' onkeypress='doSomething()' />

function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById('live_update').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

2.standard jquery method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#live_update').on('keyup', function(){
            $('#user_radius').val($('#live_update').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

3.find a front-end framework that does 2-way data binding for you such as Angular

demo: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/twowaydatabinding/

Answer (score 1):

this should do the job:

```
<input id="user_radius" onkeypress="doSomething()" />

function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById('live_update').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```